# Unexpected Google geocoder API results when filtering by country

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-maps-engine

[Labé](http://bit.ly/labe-gn) is a city in Guinea. It is the capital of the Labé region and the Labé prefecture

When I use the [Google Geocoder API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to geocode [labe] with no filters, I get three results in Guinea: One for the locality, one for the level 1 admin area, and one for the level 2 admin area:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=labe

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Labé",
               "short_name" : "Labé",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Guinea",
               "short_name" : "GN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Labé, Guinea",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 12.4428371,
                  "lng" : -11.109311
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 11.0049169,
                  "lng" : -13.027551
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 11.641159,
               "lng" : -11.8891721
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 12.4428371,
                  "lng" : -11.109311
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 11.0049169,
                  "lng" : -13.027551
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Labe",
               "short_name" : "Labe",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Labé Prefecture",
               "short_name" : "Labé Prefecture",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Labé",
               "short_name" : "Labé",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Guinea",
               "short_name" : "GN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Labe, Guinea",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 11.3544994,
                  "lng" : -12.2434901
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 11.2847299,
                  "lng" : -12.3362733
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 11.316667,
               "lng" : -12.283333
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 11.3544994,
                  "lng" : -12.2434901
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 11.2847299,
                  "lng" : -12.3362733
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      // (omitted result for Elbe)
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Labé Prefecture",
               "short_name" : "Labé Prefecture",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Guinea",
               "short_name" : "GN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Labé Prefecture, Guinea",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 11.739439,
                  "lng" : -11.994902
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 11.140461,
                  "lng" : -12.605376
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 11.3541939,
               "lng" : -12.3463875
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 11.739439,
                  "lng" : -11.994902
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 11.140461,
                  "lng" : -12.605376
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

When I narrow by country, however, I only receive the level 1 admin area (region):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=labe&components=country:gn

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Labé",
               "short_name" : "Labé",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Guinea",
               "short_name" : "GN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Labé, Guinea",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 12.4428371,
                  "lng" : -11.109311
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 11.0049169,
                  "lng" : -13.027551
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 11.641159,
               "lng" : -11.8891721
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 12.4428371,
                  "lng" : -11.109311
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 11.0049169,
                  "lng" : -13.027551
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Generally the geocoder API seems to have trouble with cities that share their names with administrative regions; neither of these searches return locality results, only admin areas:

- Kankan (pop. 193,000)
  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=kankan&components=country:gn
- Boké (pop. 62,000)
  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=boke&components=country:gn

Any idea what gives? Google knows about these cities - if you search using the Maps interface, it finds them immediately.

Comment: try https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=labe&components=city:gn

Comment: @Mapperz "city" is not a valid component type and that doesn't give any better results.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem with cities in Turkey.
Have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: @HerbCaudill install this geocoder https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geocoder/1.8.0 it makes is much easier to geocode and you can use google, bing maps, osm, etc...

Comment: Same issue with Brussels, Belgium and Halifax, Canada. Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600014/google-maps-geocoder-not-returning-locality